# issue with regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this string in format of XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>n
  <objectA>n
  <command>Existing</command>n
  <status>OK</status>n
  <values>a lot of values....</values>n
  </objectA>
```

I want to split it to array of string just with the value and content

```
     [0] objectA = ""
     [1] command = Existing
     [2] status = ok
     [3] values = a lot of values....
```

I tried

```
 result = result.replaceAll(">n<", "><"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<*?>*?</*?>"); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

but is is not working for me

Comment: I'm not sure but have you tried to replace all line breaks(\n) first and then run your pattern. What isn't working? Any error message?

Comment: Why you don't use xml parser?

Comment: You would be better off using an XML parser

Comment: Just use an XML parser. Trying to parse with a regex is extremely fragile even if you get it working. Also, are those "n" characters at the end of the lines supposed to be line breaks ("\n")?

Comment: I tried also to remove the and it is also didn't work

Comment: [You must not use regex to parse XML.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1907906)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use an XML Parser?

```
Element docElem = document.getDocumentElement();

NodeList children = docElem.getChildNodes();

List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int x = 0; x < children.getLength(); x++)
{
     // Do what you want with children. That came out wrong.
}
```